# how to make 2 fixed-width sidebar div and 1 flexible-width main div?

Tags: css

basically my html code looks like:

```
 <div id="leftbar"></div>
 <div id="content"></div>
 <div id="rightbar"></div>
```

how do i code it with css so that the all 3 divs will be side by side and leftbar and rightbar have a fixed width while content will be flexible to fill out the webbrowser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

How about this one: http://www.glish.com/css/7.asp

Comment: that page doesnt make fixed width columns blended with flexible columns

Comment: @noname: added a different one. Note, there are several different layouts on the mathewjamestaylor.com site, one of which is what you're looking for if you poke around.

Comment: worked perfectly. saved me a lot of time, just copy and use. should be like this, cause i as a web developer just want to mind critical functions and not reinvent the wheel all the time. do you got other useful links to css/html to save time?

Comment: Actually I always start with glish. He has a set of links somewhere on his /css site that has a complete list of tutorials. Some are still there, but a lot are link-rotted.

Answer (score 2):

Float the leftbar left, and give content a margin-left value equal to (or greater than) the width of the leftbar. Float the rightbar right, and give content a margin-right value equal to  (or greater than) the width of rightbar.

```
.nav1    { width:200px; float:left; }
.nav2    { width:200px; float:right; }
.content { margin:0 210px; }
.clear   { clear:both; }
```

--

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="nav1">Main Nav Items</div>
  <div class="nav2">Other Nav Items</div>
  <div class="content">Content goes here</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: but its something wrong with this approach. when i minimize the browser the rightbar moves beneath everything.

Answer (score 0):

Now css has flexbox model.

You should read the specification to get the flexible layout of webpage

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/